# Cannot format datetime in SQL Server Reporting Services report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting

None of the previous questions/answers on this topic are working for me; I'm a bit baffled. I've inherited my first SQL Server Reporting Services Report Builder report and was given the seemingly simple task of changing what was a date to a datetime. As you can see below I've successfully modified the underlying query and am getting back datetime types but I cannot FORMAT them as such on the report.

Results of my query:

[image]

My first instinct was that simply changing the type of the column (`FirstProcessorCompletedDate`) from date to datetime would make cue the report tool in on displaying date and time, but no luck. So...

Previous experience with report building tools told me to take the existing reference to the field and replace it with a format statement for that field, kind of like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, whatever I add here is getting interpreted as LITERALS by the report builder upon execution.  AND YES, I DID TRY AN "=" IN FRONT OF THE FORMAT STATEMENT.  This is just one variation of what I've tried.

[image]

Clearly this is not the old SSRS-type report building I am used to.  I've Googled the heck out of this and searched Stack Overflow but no joy on the answer.  I've looked a little at Calculated Fields but this seems like overkill.  I don't want to calculate something, just format it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't used SSRS for long time, but I reckon that you can format a cell as a text and then formulas are shown as literals. Something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify the underlying query, that was your first mistake. `date(time)` data types don't have a format, they are binary values and your presentation layer changes that to a readable format. Once you change the "format" of a `date(time)` data type in SQL Server it is **no longer** a `date(time)` datatype, it's a `varchar`, and `Format` does not work on a `varchar`. How would you format the `varchar` value `'Hello, my name is Jane.'` to the style `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`? You can't, and the same applies to a string representing a date.

Return the value of your column as a `datetime` to SSRS (don't convert it), and then change the **Format Property** of your cell in SSRS (hit F4 when you have the cell selected and you'll open up the cell's property pane) and change the format to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I do understand that data types don't have formats; what I was saying is that the original query returned a DATE without any time data; I modified it to return DATETIME.  This correctly gives the binary info needed to provide the granularity of data needed.  Having said that, Your tip on F4 and formatting is EXACTLY what I needed and the report I inherited is working perfectly now thanks to your answer, which I am marking as correct.   Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have helped @markaaronky. The format property is the way to go when you need a data type to look a certain way; I've also (personally) found the `Format` function to be unreliable.